# Why does CMake Fail to Link Libbitcoin C++?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have recently installed CMake in order to write code to make use of Libbitcoin in C++ but I am having a hard time, I was trying to build the example code on GitHub [here](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-system/wiki/Examples-from-Addresses-and-HD-Wallets).  And it haters been going terribly. I can't manage to link the library right in CMake, here is my code. I read and people were saying that I should try Autoconf but I have no idea how to even start that as I know nothing about Autoconf. I have CMake 3.16, and installed Libbitcoin with brew but alias were made in /usr/local/include for the library, I am on Mac OS X 10.15. The CMake runs fine but when running "make", it responds with:

```
Scanning dependencies of target CreateAddr
main.cxx:1:10: fatal error: bitcoin/bitcoin.hpp: No such file or directory
1 | #include <bitcoin/bitcoin.hpp>
|          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Here is my CMake text:
[image]
Please all help is appreciated I am beyond lost.

Comment: Where did you set the value of `${btcLib}`. It's not set in the picture of text. Also why are you posting a picture of text instead of the text itself?

Comment: The error message means that none of your include directories contains the header `bitcoin/bitcoin.hpp`.

Comment: I expect that `/usr/local/include` is in the default search path so is there no `bitcoin.hpp` file in `/usr/local/include/bitcoin` ?

Comment: `/usr/local/include/bitcoin` seems wrong for the linker path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to be sure without knowing the specifics of your installation, but it appears that your include directory paths may be overlapping with what is specified for the header in `main.cxx`. The [`include_directories()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_directories.html) call tells the compiler to include headers from this directory:

```
/usr/local/include/bitcoin
```

Then, in `main.cxx`, you're including the file with `bitcoin/bitcoin.hpp`. Combining these suggests the file is located here:

```
/usr/local/include/bitcoin/bitcoin/bitcoin.hpp
```

The error states the header could not be found, so perhaps you meant to locate it here:

```
/usr/local/include/bitcoin/bitcoin.hpp
```

In that case, just remove the relative directory path from the `main.cxx` file, like this:

```
#include <bitcoin.hpp>
```

Also, you want to *link* to your `libbitcoin` library correctly. Using [`link_directories()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/link_directories.html) is not recommended. Instead, you can specify the full path to your `libbitcoin` library directly in the call to [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html). The library may not be located in `/usr/local/include/bitcoin`. With these changes, the last few lines in your CMake would look something more like this:

```
include_directories(/usr/local/include/bitcoin)
add_executable(CreateAddr main.cxx)
target_link_libraries(CreateAddr PUBLIC /your/path/to/libs/libbitcoin.so)
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed the code to remove the extra non necessary bitcoin in include directories. It builds properly now but it can't run make successfully. It gives 20 errors.

Comment: @DatagramDigger Ok, glad it helped. What are the errors? If they are unrelated to the previous error you posted, it may be worth creating a new question post.